# Why Am I getting NoErrorObjectAvailable error when ever i try to refer to the custom event of child in parent

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, html, child-to-parent, custom-event

PARENT.HTML

```
 <template>
    <lightning-layout multiple-rows>
      <!-- Top -->
      <lightning-layout-item size="12">
        <lightning-card title="Find a Boat">
        <lightning-button label='New Boat' slot=actions onclick={createNewBoat}></lightning-button>
<!--<p class="slds-var-p-horizontal_small">--> 
            <div >
              <c-boat-search-form onsearcheve={searchBoats}>
              </c-boat-search-form>
            </div>

        </lightning-card>
      </lightning-layout-item>
      <!-- Bottom -->
      <lightning-layout-item size="12" class="slds-p-top_small slds-is-relative">
        <!-- Spinner goes here -->
        <template if:true={isLoading}>
        <div >
            <lightning-spinner alternative-text="Loading" size="large" variant="brand"></lightning-spinner>
        </div>
        </template>
        <c-boat-search-results onloading={handleLoading} ondoneloading={handleDoneLoading} ></c-boat-search-results>
      </lightning-layout-item>
    </lightning-layout>
  </template>
```

Parent.JS

```
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation'


export default class BoatSearch extends  NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
     // imports
//export default class BoatSearch extends LightningElement {
    isLoading = false;

    
    // Handles loading event
    handleLoading() { 
        this.isLoading=true;
    }
    
    // Handles done loading event
    handleDoneLoading() { 
        this.isLoading=false;
    }
    
    // Handles search boat event
    // This custom event comes from the form
    searchBoats(event) { 
        const boatTypeId = event.detail.boatTypeId;
        this.template.querySelector("c-boat-search-results").searchBoats(boatTypeId);
    }
    
    createNewBoat() {
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: 'standard__objectPage',
            attributes: {
                objectApiName: 'Boat__c',
                actionName: 'new'
            }
        });
    }
  }
```

CHILD HTML

```
<template>
    <lightning-layout>
      <lightning-layout-item class="slds-align_absolute-center">
      <template if:true={searchOptions}>
      <lightning-combobox class="slds-align_absolute-center"    value={selectedBoatTypeId}  options={searchOptions}   onchange={handleSearchOptionChange} ></lightning-combobox>
      </template>
     </lightning-layout-item>
    </lightning-layout>
  </template>
```

CHILD.JS

```
import { LightningElement, track, wire } from 'lwc';
import getBoatTypes from '@salesforce/apex/BoatDataService.getBoatTypes';

export default class BoatSearchForm extends LightningElement {
@track selectedBoatTypeId = '';
@track error = undefined;
@track searchOptions;
@wire(getBoatTypes)
boatTypes({ error, data }) {
    if (data) {
        this.searchOptions = data.map((type) =>{return { label: type.Name, value: type.Id };});
        this.searchOptions.unshift({ label: "All Types", value: "" });
    } else if (error) {
        this.error = error;
        this.searchOptions=undefined;
        //console.error('error => ', error); // error handling
    }
}
 
    handleSearchOptionChange(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    this.selectedBoatTypeId = event.detail.value;
    const searchEvent =  this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("searcheve", {
    detail: {
    boatTypeId: this.selectedBoatTypeId
    }
    }));
       
     }
    }
```

Comment: Hi Sairam, You can use the `{}` button to format your code.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SFSE. Questions tend to get answered more often and more quickly when they include information that helps pinpoint the specifics of the problem. As it stands you have given a code dump and a rather vague indication of the error. Please [edit] the question to include indiction as to exactly where you are seeing the problem.